# How to fix 'polluted' pull request on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a large project with a large team. I got a task to edit 1 file and push it to GitHub in it's own branch and create a pull request, which I have done.

However, the branch/pull request has become 'polluted' - it now contains thousands of files and commits, no longer just my 1 commit and 1 file.

Is there anyway I can revert it back to my old commit?

Comment: Can you tell us what has happened to this branch since you created the PR?  If no _other_ commits have come in, then I would explain this as owing to the destination branch being substantially different than your branch.  It could be that some other intermediate branch should go into `master` first before yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): you should be able to reset your local PR branch to its old HEAD

Then try again, this time by rebasing your PR branch before force pushing it:

```
git checkout my-pr-branch
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
git push --force
```

That should push only your own local commit.